# Google compute engine sending post request issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am deploying a node server on the Google compute engine that takes bitbucket webhook request, change the format and sends POST request to Discord(it is basically a converter between bitbucket and discord). I can get the webhook request from the bitbucket by changing firewall rule. However, I can't make the server to send POST request to discord. What kind of google cloud firewall rule do I need to add? Thanks!

Comment: How are you sending the POST request? Some code might be helpful so we can look for any problems there.

By default, it SHOULDN'T be blocking anything. You can check the documentation here on how the Firewalls handle. Default is to allow outgoing and forbid incoming, but there are certain types of traffic that are always denied: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls

Comment: Another thing to add here - this sounds like the perfect kind of workload for Google Cloud Functions!  We use Cloud Functions for webhooks coming from GitHub.  They're nice because you have to deal with a lot less infrastructure, like firewall rules :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, I am trying google cloud functions. I may ask you for a help with my code if google cloud functions doesn't work. If it doesn't work on cloud functions, the problem should be my code.